# Telegram Qt Ld status 1 with no explanation

Tags: qt, telegram

I just try to compile Telegram Qt, and this is the first time I got this kind of ld error. Usually when have ld error it has description like "can not resolve something". But today I just get

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thats the only error i got, no further info. Is there anyone has this experience?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ld is probably looking for something and unable to find an entry point or even does not have access to the files needed.  Try looking for any log files from the compiler, that has the first hint to what is wrong.

Comment: Ah the problem is there no more space on my hdd. Problem solved.